# Unable to setup rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, centos7

I'm trying to setup my rails environment for development on CentOS7. When I try to create the database I get the error

`PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "antarr", database "postgres", SSL off`. Below are my configurations

#### /var/lib/pgsql/10/data/pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             postgres                                trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all            all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident

hostnossl all           all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

#### postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that in the local type you have privileges for the user **postgres** change it to **all** so that **antarr** user can connect to your DB or in your database.yml set **username** as **postgres**

for more info see [HERE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: This helped, but instead of modifying `database.yml` I added `local all antarr                                  trust`